# Is it possible to share camera with iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I have a webpage with WebRTC to do web conference. Inside this webpage there is an iframe that also use camera to recognize some pictures(Use tensorflow API).

Current situation is that when the iframe loaded, the WebRTC camera will stop. Is it possible that these two pages share the camera that no one will be stopped by the other?

The browser is Safari.

Comment: Both frames share the same-origin?

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, it is

Comment: Then you should be able to pass the MediaStream to the other context without any trouble through either `iframe.contentWindow` or `parent` (though the MediaStream would die when the "origin" document dies). However just requesting two MediaStreams should "just work™": https://jsfiddle.net/v1zat5bs/ (it does work for me on Safari 15.1). Certainly something is wrong in your configuration and you'd be better fixing that instead. Could you please try to make an [MCVE]?

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for your reply. The Mac Safari is good but on iPad Safari it can't work. When the iframe camera starts the parent frame's camera video went to black. But the audio was still working, so I am wondering when the iframe is closed, can we just hook up the video only again(without reconnect because the connection is still there)?

Comment: @Kaiido doesn't Safari summarily refuse to have getUserMedia called more than once (possibly on iOS this won't work due to the common restriction to have just a single camera device open at a time)

Comment: A possible workaround would be to paint the camera to a canvas, grab the base64 encoded image and transfer that to the iframe.

Comment: @PhilippHancke I don't have an iOS device to test this out. But they probably don't need to draw this MediaStream to a canvas, simply passing the MediaStream object should be enough: https://jsfiddle.net/2upstxq9/ (they said their iframes are same-origin)

Comment: And in case of cross-origin frames, transferring VideoFrames when available would probably be better than dataURLs, followed by ImageBitmaps from the canvas, with Blobs as last resort.